# is this still a valid question for SO or should it be migrated to SU?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348285/how-to-automatically-mount-my-portable-disk-with-ntfs-3g-driver-on-mac-os-x?rq=1

It has answers marked as ok.

Comment: PS. It can't be migrated because it's too old.

Comment: Close All teh Things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most definitely a [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) question. Unfortunately, as animuson noted in the comments, it's too old to be migrated.

IMHO, it should just be deleted, as in [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)'s context, it's a bad question (by being offtopic).

Comment: I think that, instead of deleting, there should be exceptions to the "too old to migrate" rule for clear cases like this. It's unfortunate to remove content that could be useful in general.